# Print Shipment Labels for Flat Rate Method in Magento?

Tags: php, magento

I have look for a way to print shipping labels for FLat Rate Shipment Method but unable to find one .
I tried extension cubex Address label  Extension but its not working and giving me error

```
Fatal error: Class 'Cubix_AddressLabel_Block_Adminhtml_System_Config_Form_Fieldset_Modules_AddressLabel' not found in /home4/user/public_html/demo/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php on line 590
```

Is there any other way ?

Comment: If you get that error, the plugin is probably malfunctioning, or you have added a `getChildHtml()` without properly injecting the block into the backend... To know what exactly is wrong is (at least for me) impossible to say...

Comment: I just need to print shipping labels customised and shipment method is fixed Flat rate how can i do it ? any idea

Comment: what do you mean by "customised"?

Comment: Well just want to print shipping labels in simple words where it displays address and a logo of my courier service

Comment: There is no simple way to do this... I have done this twice before, and it takes about a day to implement (making sure everything is in the correct place in PDF's). There is no definitive HOWTO guide for doing this (at least not to my knowledge). Look for a certified developer in your area who can help you implement this...

Comment: i am a developer myself just looking for a short way to do it :)

Comment: If you are a Magento developer, you should know there are no shortcuts ;S

Comment: I found this plugin but damn its not working  but its not working  http:  //www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/cubix-address-label-printing.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm the developer for this module. This error was caused because your module was not installed correctly. The AddressLabel.php solution you have given is actually what was supposed to be there in the first place if the module was installed correctly.

Comment: I could replicate this error on my end as well - it happens when you install the module via connect manager - for some reason it creates directory AddressLabel.php instead of a file - @Abdul Basit provided the most accurate and quick solution for this issue.

This problem more likely won't happen when installed manually.

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed the problem related to CUbix Plugin . Just go to this directory

```
app/code/local/Cubix/AddressLabel/Block/Adminhtml/System/Config/Form/Fieldset/Modules
```

there will be a directory named AddressLabel.php delete that directory create a new file in Modules folder name it  AddressLabel.php with this code as follows

```
<?php

class Cubix_AddressLabel_Block_Adminhtml_System_Config_Form_Fieldset_Modules_AddressLabel extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_System_Config_Form_Fieldset {


    protected function _getHeaderHtml($element)
    {
        $html = parent::_getHeaderHtml($element);
        $html = '<img src="' . $this->getSkinUrl('images/cubix_addresslabel.png') . '" alt="Cubix Address Label explanation" />' . $html;
        return $html;
    }
}
```

Problem Resolved